# pgsql - how to get the sum of only the not null values in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in pgsql. There is a json object in a specific column and I need to get the sum of the data in that json object. It works perfectly until it hits with a null value.
There can be empty values for the elements in the json object. But when I get the sum it gives an error.

> Statement could not be executed (22P02 - 7 - ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function gettargetreports(date,date) line 3 at RETURN QUERY)

Here is my stored procedure. How can I walk around that issue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.gettargetreports(
IN start_dates date,
IN end_dates date)
RETURNS TABLE(report_id integer, report_name text, profileid text, 
    conv integer, visits integer, avgtime integer, revenue integer, 
    backlink integer, newvisits integer, bouncerate integer, roomnights 
    integer, visibility integer, marketshare integer, pagesvisits integer, 
    transactions integer, domainauthority integer, seocontribution 
    integer, overallwebvisits integer, newvisitspercentage integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
RETURN QUERY (
    (SELECT
        rpt.report_id,
        rpt.report_name,
        rpt.report_data->>'profile' as profileId,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'conv')::int)::int as conv,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'visits')::int)::int as visits,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'avgTime')::int)::int as avgTime,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'revenue')::int)::int as revenue,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'backlink')::int)::int as backlink,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'newVisits')::int)::int as newVisits,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'bounceRate')::int)::int as bounceRate,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'roomNights')::int)::int as roomNights,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'visibility')::int)::int as visibility,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'marketshare')::int)::int as marketshare,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'pagesVisits')::int)::int as pagesVisits,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'transactions')::int)::int as transactions,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'domainAuthority')::int)::int as domainAuthority,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'seoContribution')::int)::int as seoContribution,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'overallWebVisits')::int)::int as overallWebVisits,
        sum((rpt.report_target_data->>'newVisitsPercentage')::int)::int as newVisitsPercentage
    FROM public.proc_targetreport as rpt
    WHERE (
        rpt.start_date >= (date_trunc('MONTH', start_dates))::date AND
        rpt.end_date <= (date_trunc('MONTH', end_dates))::date 
        )
        GROUP BY rpt.report_id,rpt.report_name,profileId
    )
 );
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

report_target_data is the json objects column name

Comment: I'd rather say, empty value, not the null

Answer (score 1):

you can try a monkey hack, that would work only if you have normal numeric values or empty string, eg:

```
t=# select (concat('0',('{"s":null}'::json->>'s')))::int;
 concat
--------
      0
(1 row)

t=# select (concat('0',('{"s":""}'::json->>'s')))::int;
 concat
--------
      0
(1 row)

t=# select (concat('0',('{"s":29}'::json->>'s')))::int;
 concat
--------
     29
(1 row)
```

Comment: Actually `->>` translates a JSON `null` to a SQL `null`.  For example: `select ('{"s":null}'::json->>'s')::int;`  Perhaps the OP has `"null"` values?

Answer (score 0):

A JSON `null` should translate to a SQL `null`.  And you can cast a SQL `null` to `int` just fine:

```
select ('{"s":null}'::json->>'s')::int;
-->
NULL
```

But perhaps you're not using `null`, but an empty string or a `"null"` string.  In that case you can use `case` to translate:

```
select case when col1 = 'xxx' then null else col1 end::int
from   (
       select '{"s":"xxx"}'::json->>'s' as col1
       ) sub1;
-->
NULL
```

[Example at rextester.](http://rextester.com/WZBY45399)

Comment: `sum((rpt.report_target_data::json->>'conv')::int)::int as conv` is this correct

Comment: Looks fine, a sum of integers is also an integer, so the outer `::int` is not required